# I am trying to increment an ID but for some reason it keeps resetting after the 1st ID is set

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
  struct Classes
  {      //struct specific for classes
         int class_id;
         char class_title[30];
  };
  void add_class()
  {
         //Adding class
         int i, n;
         struct Classes *addClass;
         printf("How many classes are you adding? ");
         scanf("%d", &n);

   addClass = (struct Classes*) malloc(n * sizeof(struct Classes*));
   addClass->class_id = 1;

   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
            printf("Enter class titles\n");
            scanf(" %s ", (addClass+i)->class_title);
            (addClass+i)->class_id += 1; // Supposed to increment class ID
   }
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
            printf("Class title is: %s Class ID is: %d\n", (addClass+i)->class_title, (addClass+i)->class_id);
   }
    void free(void *addclass);
   }
```

This is what happens 
How many classes are you adding? 2
Enter class titles
Geom Math
Enter class titles
Class title is: Geom Class ID is: 3
Class title is: Math Class ID is: 0

Comment: `sizeof(struct Classes*)` is the size of a *pointer* to the structure, not the size of the structure.

Comment: Besides that you only update `addClass[0].class_id`, not for any other structure in the array.

Comment: So I just take off the " * "?

Comment: Lastly, you *declare* the `free` function but you never call it.

Comment: I changed it to this:    (addClass+i)->class_id += 1;          but now it decrements

Comment: How do I call the free function?

Comment: If I'm to be honest, it almost seems like you're guessing about things. Please get a few books to read, they will help you learn properly.

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)  A read of [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) will save you an untold number of hours of frustration in the future.